# Building a deep reinforcement learning with a cnn q - approximation

Tags: python, pytorch, reinforcement-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm new in DRL. Starting from this code https://github.com/jaromiru/cwcf, I would like to substitute the MLP used for the q function approximation with a CNN, but I don't know how to do. Can anybody help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going through [this](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/reinforcement_q_learning.html) it has a detailed explanation on how to build DQN to solve the CartPole problem. You can also have a look at [this](https://lilianweng.github.io/lil-log/2018/05/05/implementing-deep-reinforcement-learning-models.html) which has implementations of many DRL algorithms

Then you can replace the code in agent.py present in repo with DQN agent code

Comment: Thanks, the first link is really usefull. Now, my next question is about the input size of conv1d() because  I'm not working with images and moreover the code in repo is for multi-agent environment. My input shape  is [1000,2,17] , in which the fist one represents the number of agents, the other are the state. I should resize my input to feed cnn. How I should do ?

Comment: we generally use cnns when the data has spatial relationship. before you try using cnn understand if the data you are dealing with has some spatial information which can be extracted to solve the task. conv1d operates on 1dimention so if you are sure that you want to do conv1d you may flatten or reshape the data. For very low dimensional data if you increase your model complexity the model might overfit the data

Comment: Yes, I should use conv1d. My issue is about hot to reshape my data to give conv1d the correct input, but I'm confused about the presence of multi agents. If I reshape the data, the first dimension should be the batch size, right?

Comment: Yes if your are trying to generate data for a single policy using multi agent setting then you have 1000 samples of data

Comment: So, I tried as input, supposing a conv1d(17,17,1,stride = 1) (I don't know if it has sense actually), (-1,17,1). Can be a correct way?

Comment: I actually didn't get your the question. You should be using the conv operator based on the input size and the desired output side and the rest all parameters are experimental